# XQuery average value of attribute

Tags: xquery

I have the following XML input

```
<foo>
<bar a=1 b=25/>
<bar a=2 b=30/>
<bar a=1 b=35/>
<bar a=2 b=40/>
<foo>
```

and I need to get the following result

```
<foo>
<bar a=1>average of b = 30</bar>
<bar a=2>average of b = 35</bar>
<foo>
```

I have hard time to do distinct value of a.

I have

```
<foo>
{for $e in doc(XXX.xml)/foo/bar
   return
       <bar a="distinct-values(data($e/@a))">
       {for $c in distinct-values(data($e/@a))
            return avg(data($e/@b))}
       </bar>}
</foo>
```

What am I missing?

Comment: you got the problem resolved?

Comment: yes thanks you very much

Answer (score 1):

If your XQuery processor supports XQuery 3.0 you can use the group by construct, which is exactly designed for such a use case and, in my opinion, much nicer to read:

```
<foo>{
  for $el in doc(XXX.xml)/foo/bar
  let $a := $el/@a
  group by $a
  return
         <bar a="{$a}">average of b = {avg($el/@b)}
         </bar>
}
</foo>
```

It groups each `bar` element by the `a` attribute and computes (and outputs) the average of the `b` attribute.

Answer (score 0):

I hope this is what you are looking for.

```
let $doc :=  <foo>
              <bar a="1" b="25"/>
              <bar a="2" b="30"/>
              <bar a="1" b="35"/>
              <bar a="2" b="40"/>
             </foo>

let $result := <foo>
                {for $a in fn:distinct-values($doc//bar/@a)
                  for $b in avg($doc//bar[@a=$a]/@b)
                   return
                       <bar a="{$a}">
                       averge of b = {$b}
                       </bar>
                }
               </foo>
return $result
```

Proper for loop will do.